# Zoom H2 recordings with two different mic settings. How can I match them now?

Tags: audio-recording, microphone, stereo

I have a dilemma. I recorded live flute in a concert hall yesterday using my mac and the Zoom H2. I used the 2-channel setting that uses both the front and back mics, creating a stereo file. When I recorded the same thing today, I forgot to change the mic setting, hence this recording is made only from the front mic, creating a single stereo file with left and right.

I now need to cut/paste clips and make them match. How do I proceed?

Comment: Do you mean that you first recorded with the four-channel dual-stereo setting, and *then* recorded with two-channel stereo?

Comment: Almost, the first recording is made with the 2-channel setting, not the 4-channel setting. Hence, one channel has the front mic signal and the other channel the rear mic signal.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest thing to do would be to turn your two stereo recordings into two mono recordings. You might be able to do this by summing your left and right channel, but it is safer to pick either the left channel or the right channel and use that. This is because you might have phase cancellation when summing the two channels to mono.

Now that you have gotten rid of the differing stereo image, you just need to match levels. Use an audio editor like [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net) to reduce the level of the louder recording until it matches the quieter recording.

If you want to try to match the [stereo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereophonic_sound) image, then you need to dive into stereo processing. There are [psychoacoustic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychoacoustics) techniques that can help you manipulate the perceived stereo image. What exactly you need to do will depend on your recording and desired outcome.

Comment: I really do not quite understand what you are saying here.

Comment: What audio editing tools have you worked with?

Comment: I am using Adobe Audition CS6 at the moment, but also used Sony SounddForge in the past.

Comment: Try taking your two sound files and converting them both to mono. Be sure not to overwrite the original files when saving. Next, adjust the volume of the louder file until it flows smoothly with the quieter file. Finally, render these two files into a single continuous file. This process will be easier if Audition has a multitrack mode.

Comment: it is not necessarily about matching the volume. It is the fact that one of my recordings has the front sound _and_ the back sound (which picks up about 40meters worth of concert hall), compared to the other recording which only has a left and right channel of the front mic only.

Comment: In that case, just use the front sound from that recording. Convert the other recording to mono to match it by either picking the left or right channel, or by summing them both to mono. Then adjust levels to suit. You can't subtract out the reverb from the back channel, and can't have any stereo effect with that one front facing channel.

Comment: Your software should have a function called something like "convert to mono".

Comment: yes it has. You mean to sum the two mono channels of the stereo track into one?

Comment: yes, sum the stereo track. For the track with a front and back channel, you want just the front channel.